# Meteor run performance

Tags: meteor

Is there anyway to make the 'meteor' command or also known as 'meteor run' command in the console execute faster to run the app when developing? When I do little changes, I have to ctrl + C in the command line and meteor run (I do this because sometimes the hot code push takes time to take effect after I put the code so just ctrl + C and run it again) and it takes up like a min or two to start running again cause the app is getting big. Is there any way to make it fast while on development or there's nothing I can do about it?

Comment: At the moment there's not much you can do about it. We also experienced this and switched to a solution which allows us to work outside of meteor, leverage webpack for building, and inject the generated files into Meteor. It's similar to this: https://github.com/jedwards1211/meteor-webpack-react

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I've seen cause this is files in the /public directory. If you store more than a small number of images or other files in there, it can make the app take a really long time to start up and even crash on hot code pushes.

Comment: Yea I think that might be one of the reason.. My /public directory size is 38 MB. It's because I'm using a template.